# Customize AddAddress Function of phpmailer to add multiple addresses?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

First of all, sorry if it sounds a bit weird.

What I am trying to do is customize `AddAddress` function of phpmailer so that I can explode the email ID variable which contains email ids separated by comma.

**Example :**`$address = "ganesh.salunkhe@abc.com,ganesh@abc.com";`

**Original AddAddress Function of phpmailer:**

```
function AddAddress($address, $name = "") {
    if(!$this->checkUnique($address)){
        return;
    }
    $cur = count($this->to);
    $this->to[$cur][0] = trim($address);
    $this->to[$cur][1] = $name;
}
```

**What I want it to be ?**

```
    function AddAddresses($address, $name = "") {
    if(!$this->checkUnique($address)){
        return;
    }
    $cur = count($this->to);
    $emails=    explode(",", $address);
    for($i=0;$i<count($emails);$i++){
        $this->to[$cur][0] = trim($agent_email[$i]);
        $this->to[$cur][1] = $name;
    }
}
```

But since phpmailer itself is adding addresses at 0 index as

`$this->to[$cur][0]`

hence it seems nearest to impossible.

I know I can do something like this :

```
$emails = explode(",", $address);
foreach ($emails as $email) {    
        $email->AddAddress($email);    
}
```

But there are thousands of occurrences of  `AddAddress($email);` in my application so it seems tedious job.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: _“But since phpmailer itself is adding addresses at 0 index”_ – that is the _second level_ index only, and does not make this “impossible” at all.

Comment: You're going to have to iterate over something eventually, so I'd say just go with your last example - PHP's array operations are extremely fast - adding a thousand addresses really won't take long, and by adding them directly you're also bypassing validation, which isn't a good idea. You might like to look at the static `parseAddresses` method which may save you some code.